# datetimepicker (jquery) inline no se muestra

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

no consigo que se ejecute correctamente el calendario, cuando pulso sobre un botón si se ve bien. pero si no pulsas nada se ve solo el marco.
Es el datetimepicker de jquery

```js
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
                inline: true,
                sideBySide: true
         });
   
  $.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: Mira este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993506/jquery-datetimepicker-inline-is-showing-blank-data-on-first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo mejor es que actualices a la última versión del plugin (2.5.20) ya que en la versión 2.1.1 existía un [bug](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/31) relacionado con lo que comentas

```js
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
                inline: true,
                sideBySide: true
         });
   
  $.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="datepicker"></div>
```